# How to fix issue with @input decorator while passing data from parent to child using set?

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to share data from a parent component to a child component,I was able to pass the data to the child component using @input but I want the data in the child to be in sync whenever there is a change in the parent component,I was trying to use the set() method but I am getting an error as
"If 'app-chat' is an Angular component and it has 'childMessage' input, then verify that it is part of this module."

this is my app.module.ts snippet

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ChatComponent } from './chat/chat.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ChatComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

child component-------

```
import { DataService } from './../data.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatObject } from '../chat-object'



@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.scss']
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  childVal: any;


  @Input()
  set name(childMessage: any) {
    this.childVal = childMessage;
    console.log("updated child" + this.childVal);
  };

  get name(): any {
    return this.childVal;
  }
}
```

parent component.ts------------

```
message: string;

chatClick(text){
  console.log("inside parent" + text);
  this.message = text;
}
```

parent component.html---------

```
 <app-chat [childMessage]="message"></app-chat>
```

On running the above code, I am getting the following error in the browser

> Can't bind to 'childMessage' since it isn't a known property of 
>               'app-chat'.
>                1. If 'app-chat' is an Angular component and it has 
>               'childMessage' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>                2. If 'app-chat' is a Web Component then add 
>                'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this 
>                component to suppress this message.
>                 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the 
>                '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("][childMessage]="message">

What I want is that every time the `chatClick()` function is invoked I want
the value in the child component to be automatically updated at that instant?

Comment: You need to read [this](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be this?

```
@Input('childMessage')
set name(childMessage:any){
  this.childVal=childMessage;
  console.log("updated child"+this.childVal);
};
```